# rspec-rails stopped stubbing views in controller test after upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

After upgrading my Rails application to version 6, rspec stopped stubbing view rendering. (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/5-0/docs/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default)

I have tried several rspec and rspec-rails versions but result is always the same.

The expected behavior is that calling render should result in an empty string, but instead calling a controller action in spec is rendering the template like it would normally.

Calling `render_views false` in the example group has not effect. `render_views?` returns `false` in the example.

When I debug the controller action with `binding.pry`, in Rails 5, calling `render` returns `""`. In Rails 6, calling `render` renders the real template.

the example is as simple as it can be:

```
      it "is success" do
        get 'index'
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the loop here, OP figured out this within a GitHub issue:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2517

> This was caused by setting `view_paths` in `before_action` callback and using this new path to set a layout on the controller. Apparently in previous versions of Rails this worked, but now it's necessary to set `view_paths` on class level (using `prepend_view_paths` or similar) for stubbing to work.

Comment: how did you fix it? I am having the similar issue. When I am debugging into rspec view_rendering, I can find three paths there (app/view, actiontext-6.0.4.7/app/views, actionmailbox-6.0.4.7/app/view). So how did you fix this eventually? Did you set the prepend the actiontext views path to the view_paths? Or in other ways. thaks